# Translate MySQL error messages to new language

Tags: mysql, xampp

I want to translate MySQL's error messages. I tried:

1. Added new language to `sql/share/errmsg-utf8.txt`'s top line.
   [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPtvf.png)
2. Translated some error messages.
   [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sycC4.png)

But there is no `comp_err` or `sql/share/cmake_install.cmake` in mysql folder and in shell.

I'm using xampp v3.3.0. Also tried MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never edit directly the file installed.

Instead, modify the source code and build the error messages file again.

What you should do:

- Create a git branch based on MySQL source tree (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server), for the proper release (say 8.0)
- Do a full build (this will create the `comp_err` utility too)
- Read instructions in file `share/errmsg_readme.txt`
- Edit file `share/messages_to_clients.txt` with the new translation
- Commit the changes in git
- Do a build again

This will create the file containing error messages with the new translation, which can be installed.